# How do you convert a subquery to work with entity framework?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

In the past I would create a view for this but know there has to be a 'right way'.

Say I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    C.CustomerID
    ,C.ClientID
    ,C.Email
    ,C.PhoneNum
    ,C.PhotoCredits
    ,C.CreateDt
    ,C.Accessed
    ,C.Name
    ,C.Notes
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PHOTOS P WHERE P.CUSTOMERID = C.CustomerID) as "COUNT"
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PHOTOS P WHERE P.CUSTOMERID = C.CustomerID AND PURCHASEDT is not Null) as "PURCHASED" 
FROM CUSTOMERS
```

In my **controller**, I currently have this:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    Guid clientID = Guid.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    return db.Customers.Where(c => c.ClientID == clientID).AsQueryable();
}
```

Is there something I could add to my model to include these counts, or is there a way to add them in the controller so that they can be used in my view?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var q = from c in db.Customers
        where c.ClientId = clientId
        select new 
        {
          c.CustomerID,
          c.ClientId,
          //. . . 
          Count = c.Photos.Count,
          PurchasedCount = c.Photos.Where( p => p.PurchaseDate != null )
        };
```

Comment: Wow OK.  Instead of listing each column in Customers, how would you do like "*" ?  And for the c.Photos to work I assume I need `public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }` in my Customer model?

Comment: I went ahead and added each column, but still curious if there's a way to `select *`.  Also, i believe that where clause needs 2 '=' : `where c.ClientID == clientID` .  Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Been trying to get this to work but it's telling me it can't convert my model to this anonomous type.  How would I add the photo count & purchased count to the model?